# /fp:fast vs :fp:precise what kind of errors can I encounter?

Tags: c++, floating-accuracy

I'm wondering what kind of errors I can encounter if I set /fp:fast instead of fp:precise?
I work under MSV10

I perform /,*,+,- operations on double with max digits equal to 8, like 1.4379294 (currency rate).

Comment: You may want to take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289157(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Do *not* use standard floats for currency operations. You almost certainly want to use either decimal floats or fixed-point arithmetic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same errors you always get with *double* calculations: you never get more than 15 significant digits after you convert the result to decimal, the rest are just random noise digits.  The difference between /fp:fast and /fp:precise is what happens to those noise digits.

The /fp:precise option solves a problem with the x86 FPU, it stores intermediate results in the FPU registers with 80 bits of precision.  Which can cause subtly different noise digit values if the intermediate value is kept in a register.  With /fp:precise, the code generator is forced to flush those values back to memory, truncating them back to 64 bits.  That's slow, but does generate more consistent noise.  Which matters if you commit the sin of comparing floating point values for equality without an epsilon.

Too much fud for most accountants, using a math library that counts with 10 fingers instead of 2 is a common solution.  Which addresses the noise digit problem by eliminating the ones that are generated when you convert numbers from base 10 to base 2.  Code will be slow, much slower than /fp:precise since all calculations are made in software without hardware acceleration.  But typically not an issue in accounting applications.

Comment: nice answer. you confirm me that if I use espilon to compare two double, I will not get more problems that I am with /fp:precise ? so as fp:fast is faster that fp:precise I will not see any reasons to stay with fp:precise

Comment: yes I meant decimal point. so depending of the calculation, the first digit which can be considering as noise will not be the same? it is what your last comment mean ?

Comment: Just count them off from the left, ignoring the decimal point.  Noise starts at the 16th digit.  Or earlier if your calculation is losing significant digits, subtracting two numbers that are nearly the same for example.

Comment: OK sorry to insist but i want to be sure to well understand...the difference between precise and fast affect only the 16th digit and beyond ?

Comment: Yes, that's what my answer says.

Comment: just a doubt in a 64 bit processor, FPU registers are still 80 bits of precision not 128 bits ?